# CSS matrix calculation

Tags: javascript, css, matrix

Been trying to sort this out for a few days and I am not sure if the CSS matrix is different from standard graphics matrices, or if I have something wrong (likely I have something wrong).

I am primarily trying to figure out how to rotate on the X and Y axis. When I use "transform: rotateX(2deg) rotateY(2deg) translate3d(0px, -100px, 0px);" and I use javascript to grab the matrix style, this is what I am able to output.

```
0.9993908270190958,  -0.001217974870087876, -0.03487823687206265, 0,
0,                    0.9993908270190958,   -0.03489949670250097, 0,
0.03489949670250097,  0.03487823687206265,   0.9987820251299122,  0,
0,                  -99.93908270190957,      3.489949670250097,   1
```

But if I try to calculate the matrix using javascript (with 2 degrees on both X and Y) I get

```
 0.9993908270190958,    0,                   -0.03489949670250097, 0, 
-0.001217974870087876,  0.9993908270190958,  -0.03487823687206265, 0, 
 0.03487823687206265,   0.03489949670250097,  0.9987820251299122,  0, 
 0.1217974870087876,  -99.93908270190957,     3.487823687206265,   1
```

Now while several numbers are different in the second one, I believe one number is causing the problem. Note the numbers in row 1/column 2 and in row 2/column 1, for both matrices. The "-0.001217974870087876" looks to be switched. And if I understand how everything is calculated that is likely throwing off all the other numbers.

Here's the code I am using to create the second matrix

```
var basematrix = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0], 
    [0, -100, 0, 1]
];
function RotateWorld(y, x)
{
    var halfrot = Math.PI / 180;

    var xcos = Math.cos(x * halfrot);
    var xsin = Math.sin(x * halfrot);

    var ycos = Math.cos(y * halfrot);
    var ysin = Math.sin(y * halfrot);

    var ymatrix = [
        [ycos, 0, -ysin, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [ysin, 0, ycos, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
    ];

    var xmatrix = [
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, xcos, xsin, 0],
        [0, -xsin, xcos, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
    ];

    var calcmatrix = MatrixMultiply(ymatrix, basematrix);

    calcmatrix = MatrixMultiply(xmatrix, calcmatrix);

    calcmatrix = TransMultiply(calcmatrix);

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += calcmatrix[i][j] + ', ';
        }
    }
}

function MatrixMultiply(matrixa, matrixb)
{
    var newmatrix = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        newmatrix[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            newmatrix[i][j] = matrixa[i][0] * matrixb[0][j] 
                    + matrixa[i][1] * matrixb[1][j] 
                    + matrixa[i][2] * matrixb[2][j] 
                    + matrixa[i][3] * matrixb[3][j];
        }
    }

    return newmatrix;
}
function TransMultiply(matrix)
{
    var newmatrix = matrix;
    var x = matrix[3][0];
    var y = matrix[3][1];
    var z = matrix[3][2];
    var w = matrix[3][3];

    newmatrix[3][0] = x * matrix[0][0] + y * matrix[1][0] + z * matrix[2][0];
    newmatrix[3][1] = x * matrix[0][1] + y * matrix[1][1] + z * matrix[2][1];
    newmatrix[3][2] = x * matrix[0][2] + y * matrix[1][2] + z * matrix[2][2];
    newmatrix[3][3] = x * matrix[0][3] + y * matrix[1][3] + z * matrix[2][3] + newmatrix[3][3];
    if (newmatrix[3][3] != 1 && newmatrix[3][3] != 0)
    {
        newmatrix[3][0] = x / w;
        newmatrix[3][1] = y / w;
        newmatrix[3][2] = z / w;
    }
    return newmatrix;
}
```

My code is a bit verbose as I am just trying to learn how to work with the CSS matrix. But hopefully someone can help me get that one number into the right place.

**Edit** 
I hate to bump a post but I am running out of places to ask, so I am hoping a few more people will see it with a chance of getting an answer. I have tried every possible search to figure this out (unique questions don't get ranked very high in Google). I have probably read over 20 articles on working with matrices and they are yielding nothing. If I need to add more information please let me know. Also if there is a better place to ask let me know that as well. I would assume by now several people have looked at the code and the code must be ok, maybe my assumption that CSS is the culprit is a possibility, if so how does one track that down?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page](http://9elements.com/html5demos/matrix3d/), it explains how css 3dmatrix work. Also [here](https://github.com/arian/CSSMatrix) you have an implementation in JS of CSSMatrix object, very similar to WebKitCSSMatrix which is already included in your (webkit) browser for your use.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your implementation of `function TransMultiply(matrix) { .. }`

```
var newmatrix = matrix;
```

That isn't cloning your matrix, that's setting `newmatrix` to refer to your original matrix!  Anything using this method is going to have the original matrix and new matrix messed up.  You might want to use a method that creates new 4x4 matricies, like:

```
function new4x4matrix(){
    return  [[0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0], 
             [0, 0, 0, 0]];
}
```

and then wherever you need a new matrix, do:

```
var newmatrix = new4x4matrix();
```

Edit: err, but you may actually need a clone method: fine.

```
function cloneMatrix(matrixa)
{
    var newmatrix = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        newmatrix[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            newmatrix[i][j] = matrixa[i][j];
        }
    }

    return newmatrix;
}
```

and instead, for TransMultiply do:

```
var newmatrix = cloneMatrix(matrix);
```